# Is possible to save render_to_response template from django to server?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, caching

I created web application in Python, Django framework. Web application gets data from MongoDB database, it gets about 10000 documents from MongoDB database and works very slow. Now looking for ways to speed up my web app. So, is it possible to store result from method `render_to_response` as HTML temporarily on server? It looks like this:
I have a HTML form; when the user types data in the form and clicks on submit button, web app executes a view that gets data from the Mongo database, and sends that data via variable  `mongo_data` to `home.html`:

```
return render_to_response('home.html', {'mongo_data': mongo_data, 'request': request},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

`home.html` show data that are stored in variable `mongo_data`. In the web application, I have a lot of identical queries, for identical queries I get identical result for `home.html`. So I want to store `home.html` to folder for example `temp` on server, and when user types data in the HTML form and clicks the submit button, first to check is if `home.html` for his data is in `temp` folder; if it is, then load that `home.html`, if not then go to view which will generate new `home.html` with specific `mongo_data`.
If this is possible , it will speed up my web app a lot ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Django caching framework was made exactly for this purpose; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/.

In your case, you either cache the entire view for a period of time:

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
def my_mongo_view(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html', ...)
```

(From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache)

or you use the Low-level Cache API (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api):

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def my_mongo_view(request):
    ret = cache.get('home-rendered')
    if ret is None:
        ret = render_to_response('home.html', ...)
        cache.set('home-rendered', ret)
    return ret
```

You'll find more options for caching (e.g. inside your templates) if you just read the doc.

**P.S.** you can also parametrize your cache by a variable or user ID or something else.